# How to render a EJS template from a file?

Tags: node.js, ejs

How can I render HTML with data from a specific EJS file?

For example, I have a file `email.ejs` that contains HTML like so:

```
<a href="<%= uniqueUrl %>"><%= uniqueUrl %></a>
```

I tried the following, although keep getting multiple errors:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var html = ejs.render({uniqueUrl: passedOptions.uniqueUrl, template: 'templates/emails/reset-password.ejs'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use it with express:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index.ejs", { /* ... */ });
});
```

And you'd have your template file in the `views/` subfolder.

If you want to just use ejs:

```
ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string 
});
```

From the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs).

If this doesn't work, please give the errors you have.

PS:

> Obviously, since you do not have access to the filesystem, `ejs.renderFile()` won't work.

Rendering templates from files doesn't work if you're in a browser.

Comment: The user is clearly searching for a client side solution

Comment: @robsonrosa no, the question is tagged with `node.js`